# Searching for an object in an array by a unique int?

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say I have a Person object. In this Person there is an int and two String fields. That int will always be unique to that person, but the Person can have the same two strings. Can I search for that specific Person if it was stored in an array?

Comment: If you are going to access to person objects by the value of that integer (I assume it may be big that it cannot be used as array index) why not use a HashMap<Integer,Person>. Of course you can always scan the array for the specified value in n time or maybe you can keep the array sorted, and this way you can access in log n time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over the array:

```
public static Person findById (Person[] people, int id) {
    for (Person p : people) {
        if (p.getId() == id) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but for some reason I couldn't put it into code, so basically this will check every element in that array, and if it finds it, it will return what element number that it's at? Thanks for the reply by thee way, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Varrianda almost - it doesn't return the element's index, but the element (`Person` object) itself, which seemed much more java-esque to me.

Comment: "and if it finds it, it will return what element number that it's at?" if by that you mean that it will return index (position) in array of your element, then no, it will return element with int you are searching, not its position.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Sorry for asking such a simple question and providing no code, I was thinking I would just get a yes or no answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int getIdIndex(int iD){
    //this will find index of an specific int in an int array
    int index = 0;
    for (int iD2 : peopleId){
        if (iD2 == iD) return index;
        else index++;
    }
    return -1;

}
```

Now things may change a little bit depending on how exactly you created your objects but the main idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating the array is the most *straightforward* way, but Java 8 provides a way to get the only element you care about.  It comes wrapped in an `Optional`, so you have to unpack it yourself.

```
public static Optional<Person> findPersonById(Person[] people, int id) {
    return Arrays.stream(people).filter(p -> p.getId() == id).findFirst();
}
```

This can be invoked thus:

```
Person person = findPersonById(people, 1761283695).get();
```